# AngularJS Multiple class using expression

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a table where I need to apply two different classes, using expressions. 
1st class is applied based on following expression.
`{'Up':'class-up', 'Down':'class-down'}[a.status]`
and 2nd class is applied based on `bold: !a.read`

The classes here are `class-up`, `class-down`, `bold`.
So how should be the expression framed? I tried:

`<tr  ng-repeat="a in all" ng-class="{{'Up':'class-up', 'Down':'class-down'}[a.status],bold: !a.read}">`

`<tr  ng-repeat="a in all" ng-class="{'Up':'class-up', 'Down':'class-down'}[a.status],bold: !a.read">`

But I keep getting errors in console. What is the correct format to apply these classes based on the given expressions

Comment: isn't this quite similar to the example in the documentation? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Yes, I tried those. But I'm unable to get it to work.
The problem comes when 1st expression isn't directly dependent on a variable.

`{'Up':'class-up', 'Down':'class-down'}[a.status]` . Here `a.status` returns `Up` or `Down` as response which in turns applies `class-up` and `class-down` classes respectively.

Comment: Do you even need such a complex expression? Can you just use something like: `ng-class="{ 'class-up': a.status === 'Up', 'class-down': a.status === 'Down', 'bold': !item.read }"`

Comment: This is the final approach which I tried(works) i.e splitting into status as Up and Down in 2 components. I thought maybe status can be evaluated in a single expression instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarification from your comment:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in all" ng-class="{'class-up': a.status=='up', 'class-down': a.status=='down', 'bold': !a.read}">hello world</tr>
```